# Calling a method on an object of another class without

Tags: java, arraylist

I've got three classes: `User`, `UserManagement` (containing an arraylist of users) and `LoginController`.

```
public class UserManagement {
    //Create an arraylist that stores users
    ArrayList<User> users;

    public UserManagement() {
        users = new ArrayList<User>();
    }

    public void addUser(String userName, String fullName, String password) {
        users.add(new User(userName, fullName, password));
    }

    public void listAllUsers() {
        for (User user : users) {
            System.out.println(user.printUserInfo());
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param userName username to be searched for
     * @param password password to be searched for
     * @ return boolean for check of username/password
     */
    public boolean checkUser(String userName, String password)  {
        int index = 0;
        boolean searching = true;
        boolean match = false;
        while (searching && index < users.size()) {
            String u = users.get(index).getUsername();
            String p = users.get(index).getPassword();
            if (u.equals(userName) && p.equals(password)) {
                //its a match
                match = true;
            }
            else {
                // continue searching
                index++;
            }
        }
        return match;
    }
}
```

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable, ControlledScreen {
    @FXML
    Button loginButton;

    @FXML
    private TextField login;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField password;

    ScreensController myController;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

    public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenParent) {
        myController = screenParent;
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        UserManagement.users.checkUser(login.getText(), password.getText());
        //something like this? ^
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to call the method `checkUser` with variables I have stored in the `LoginController` class. Obviously I don't want to create a bunch of arraylists whenever I want to check login details. Is there a way of doing this to the arraylist in `UserManagement` without creating a new arraylist every time? 
The last method in `LoginController` may give better insight to what I like to achieve.

Comment: Your checkUser method seeems to be faulty, you could use the same for loop, that you used in the listAllUsers method, and once you've found the user, you should break the loop with 'break;' or just return true

Answer (score 0):

```
UserManagement.users.checkUser(login.getText(), password.getText());
```

won't work because users is defined as a member variable in UserManagement class. Whereas UserManagement.users is trying to get the class variable.

Here's a link that tells you the difference:

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/whats-the-difference-between-a-class-variable-and-an-instance-variable/

Quick fix:

1) instantiating a UserManagement instance in your LoginController class.

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable, ControlledScreen {
    @FXML
    Button loginButton;

    @FXML
    private TextField login;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField password;

    ScreensController myController;

    UserManagement usrMgmt = new UserManagement();
    ....
```

then you can do :

```
@FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        usrMgmt.checkUser(login.getText(), password.getText());
        //something like this? ^
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**A few tips :**

1) Don't initialize the ArrayList in the constructor of UserManagement Class. Think of it like "Everytime someone instantiates that Class, a new arraylist will be created...Do I want that?"

It is not appropriate and also unnecessary usage of space.The Solution here would be to have it like a property and have getters and setters for it. **This will resolve your class design conondrum of creating an ArrayList everytime the constructor is called.**

```
private ArratList<User>; {get;set;}
```

2) In the checkUser() function, you are checking existence of all users and their passwords. Never do that.
Instead, select the user and check if he exists, only then check if his password is correct or not. Return the result as appropriate (Separating errors like User does not exist or incorrect password etc).